# Linear Independence of four vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, gre-exam

Given $(1,2,3)$, $(4,5,6)$, and $(7,8,9)$.

Which is independent?

A. $(0,0,0)$ B.$(1,0,1)$ C.$(1,1,1)$ D. $(2,4,6)$ E.$(3,5,7)$

Clearly the set of given vectors is not linearly independent. My question is if they still span a subspace of $\Re^3$. If so, does this help in determining which vector will be independent?

Comment: Independence is not a property of a vector, but of a system of vectors.

Comment: Obviously the question asks about independence from the three given vectors.

Comment: No, the idea that independence could be a property of a vector, is a common mistake. So, there is no obviously here.

Comment: @user98577 A system like $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1),(1,1,1)\}$ is linearly dependent (the system). The subsystems $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$, $\{(0,1,0),(0,0,1),(1,1,1)\}$, $\{(1,0,0),(0,0,1),(1,1,1)\}$, and $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(1,1,1)\}$, are all linearly independent. We could say that the vector extracted, in each case, was dependent of the others. Dependence could be stated as a property of a vector, but relative to a system. Independence too can be said relative to a system. But we cannot say "which vector will be independent" as an absolute property of the vector.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Every subset of $\Bbb R^3$ spans a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$. In this case you could show that $$\{(1,2,3),(1,1,1)\}$$ is a basis for the subspace spanned by the original three vectors and then easily show that all but one of the choices are linear combinations of $(1,2,3)$ and $(1,1,1)$.

Comment: By Row-Reducing,
$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4  & 7 \\
         2 & 5 & 8 \\
         3 & 6 & 9  
 \end{pmatrix} $ = $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0  & 1 \\
         0 & 1 & 2 \\
         0 & 0 & 0  \end{pmatrix}$
So,
$\begin{pmatrix} x \\
                 y \\
                 z \\ \end{pmatrix}$=$t\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\
                 2 \\
                 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$
So the original vectors span a line in $\Re^3$. How do I show the basis is $(1,1,1),(1,2,3)$?

Comment: @user98577 are we supposed to know what you mean by that?

Comment: @user98577 **a** basis, instead of **the** basis. Bases are not unique.

Comment: @user98577: It wasn’t necessary to do the row-reduction. Let $V$ be the subspace spanned by the three vectors. Clearly $(1,2,3)\in V$, and $$(1,1,1)=\frac13\Big((4,5,6)-(1,2,3)\Big)\in V\;.$$ Clearly these two vectors are independent of each other, so $\dim V\ge 2$. On the other hand, you already pointed out that the original three vectors are not lin. indep., so $\dim V<3$. It follows that $\dim V=2$ and hence that $\{(1,2,3),(1,1,1)\}$ is a basis for $V$. But you don’t even need that: all you really need is the observation that $(1,2,3)$ and $(1,1,1)$ are both in $V$, since it’s easy to ...

Comment: @CarstenSchultz He/She is confusing how to test for linear independence/find a basis, with solving a homogeneous system of equations. As a result he/she computed the dual to the span of those vectors. That is why he/she is getting a one dimensional space.

Comment: ... write all but one of the answer choices as linear combinations of these.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you already know that the given vectors span a $2$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, so we are interested in the linear systems

$$x+4y=a\\2x+5y=b\\3x+6y=c$$

where $(a,b,c)$ is one of the answer choices.  The reduced form of the augmented coefficient matrix is

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&\frac{4b-5a}{3}\\0&1&\frac{2a-b}{3}\\0&0&-a+2b-c\frac{}{}\end{pmatrix}$$

Plugging in different values for $(a,b,c)$ we find that only $(1,0,1)$ makes the system inconsistent.

Comment: I am having difficulties seeing how found that particular linear system? Why is $(7,8,9)$ left out. I understand that it is a linear combination of the other two vectors. However, I have never seen a system being set up like this.